# Django form field is not displayed

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to output form field in my view.
But I'm getting:
**django.forms.widgets.Select object at 0x7f631c2cef10** instead of the html select element

**My code:**

**forms.py**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      from house.models import COUNTRY_LIST, HOUSE_TYPES
      from profile.models import Region
      self.countries = forms.Select(choices=COUNTRY_LIST, attrs={'title': 'Страна','class': 'search-r-from-select style-select'})
      self.type = forms.Select(choices=HOUSE_TYPES, attrs={'class': 'search-r-from-select style-select'})
      super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
def search_view(request):
  from house.models import House
  from house.forms import SearchForm
  if request.GET.get('initSearch', False):
     found_houses = House.get_search_result(request.GET)
     search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)
  else:
     search_form = SearchForm()

  return render_template(request, 'house/search.html', {
     'search_form': search_form
  })
```

**house/search/html**

```
  {{ search_form.countries }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to following:

```
 from house.models import COUNTRY_LIST, HOUSE_TYPES
 from profile.models import Region

 class SearchForm(forms.Form):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['countries'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRY_LIST, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'title': 'Страна','class': 'search-r-from-select style-select'}))
         self.fields['type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=HOUSE_TYPES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'search-r-from-select style-select'}))
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo (forms.py were in the original)

Comment: This code is not display anything. Now I have blank space instead of **django.forms.widgets.Select object at 0x7f631c2cef10**